# Nuxt Auth - hide client_secret

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js

When using the default laravel.passport strategy, I pass the `client_secret` and when I run `npm run generate` and search the generated code in dist, I can't find the `client_secret`; it's hidden, which is good and what I want.

However, when I use a custom strategy or local strategy and pass the `client_secret`, I can see the secret in the generated code in dist.

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      password_grant_custom: {
        _scheme: "~/auth/schemes/PassportPasswordScheme.js",
        client_id: process.env.PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_SECRET,
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: "/oauth/token",
            method: "post",
            propertyName: "access_token"
          },
          logout: false,
          user: {
            url: "api/v1/me",
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: false
          }
        }
      },
      'laravel.passport': {
        url: "https://example.com",
        client_id: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET,
        userinfo_endpoint: "https://example.com/api/v1/me",
      }
    }
  },
```

How can I hide the `client_secret` so it's not visible in public code?

Answer (score 0):

Because in laravel.passport its deleted after used when addAuthorize called. See [code](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/blob/cda679aea1df1a7dbd651584ed788d89efada567/lib/providers/_utils.js#L14)

```
  // Get client_secret, client_id and token_endpoint
  const clientSecret = strategy.client_secret
  const clientID = strategy.client_id
  const tokenEndpoint = strategy.token_endpoint

  // IMPORTANT: remove client_secret from generated bundle
  delete strategy.client_secret
```

So you need to do same for your scheme

Comment: Ahh thanks! So with a `constructor(auth, options)` function it would go at the end of the function as `delete options.client_secret`, right? Here's my [source code](https://github.com/mwargan/JustBookr-Time)

Comment: Huh, well adding it to my constructor in [the scheme](https://github.com/mwargan/JustBookr-Time/blob/master/auth/schemes/PassportPasswordScheme.js) didn't work...

Comment: @Michał what exact code that u ended up after deleting? Because if u just delete u wont be accessible further in this.options.client_secret

Comment: By doesn't work, I mean that it didn't delete anything when I added `delete options.client_secret` to the end of the constructor function in my custom scheme. `addAuthorize` seems to be on the provider level instead of the scheme level...

Comment: @Michał i mean you do assign to this.options. If you just delete it from options arg than it still will be in this.options

Comment: Ahh good point... but if I delete it in `this.options` how can I access it further down in the other functions?

Comment: @Michał  from my understanding of the code in original repo you need to assign it to local variable

Comment: So I tried to make it local by `var clientSecret = clientSecret;` and then `delete options.client_secret;` before setting `this.options`, but to no avail, the client secret still shows in the dist code... Do you think this can be done from the scheme? In the repo it's done on the provider level...

Comment: @Michał actually i have read code more carefully. What u asking doesnt make sense. In laravel password its not in generated bundle because this code is in server middleware, so its only executed during generate and the result of it saved in generated js. While your scheme just use stadrand login function which should be called from client so the secret also MUST be there to be working or it will not make sense

Comment: Hmmm - but then its un-secure right? That makes the password grant visible to everyone, a big security risk no? Any ideas on how I would authenticate with the password grant then?

Comment: @Michał i have read how it should work. Short answer - you cant use secret if u are using static site without server. You are either have to go without secret or use server side.